# Photon PUN 2+ Unity only working when I run two instances locally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, photon

So I 'm creating a game and it's using Photon PUN 2+  I made a free app with 20 CCU and copied the APP ID into unity, I made it automatically connect to rooms if they are any available, and if not create a room.
This works when I run two instances of the game on my own PC.
But when I sent it over to my friend we don't connect to the same room
If I could please get anyone to help it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe your friend is connect to another photon cloud region. You can call PhotonNetwork.ConnectToRegion(...) to ensure you are on the same region or set a fixed region in the photon settings.

Comment: that might be the case because I live in UK and he lives in Jamaica

Comment: Yes then that’s for sure the reason. I added my comment as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your friend is connect to another [photon cloud region](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/connection-and-authentication/regions).

You can either

- let user switch regions by calling PhotonNetwork.ConnectToRegion(...) to ensure they are on the same region
- or set a fixed region in the photon settings